# How to find column which contains a string

Tags: database, db2

I am using DB2 where I have a table which has 300 columns. How can I search for the column name which contains a specific string? I know the table name and the string. Is that possible in DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db2 stores its metadata in the so-called catalog. You can find the [roadmap to the catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html?pos=2) in the Db2 Knowledge Center. The view **SYCAT.COLUMNS** holds information about the columns for the tables in a database.

Without testing, you could write a query like this to search for the string:

```
select colname
from syscat.tables
where tabname=YOURTABLE and tabschema=YOURTABLESCHEMA and colname LIKE '%YOURSTRING%'
```

This would search in that table for the column names for **YOURTABLESCHEMA.YOURTABLE** and use the **LIKE** expression to search for a column name that contains **YOURSTRING**.